# Binary search tree Problem Importing names from txt in C

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I have a homework which ask fro me to insert from a text document 100 students names and IDs formatted like(Surname Name ID) ad then put  the in two binary search trees. The main BST will contain surnames and a pointer to the other BST which will contain names and IDs. This is the first time that i'm trynig to use pointers(*,->,&) so i'm LOST. I managed to import the text with the following function

```
void loadData(char fname[], Students *st){
 struct Students *new;
 root=NULL;
int i;
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(fname,"r");
if (fp == NULL) printf("File does not exist\n");
fscanf(fp, "%d", &(st->size)); //reads the number of students   
free(st->name);
st->name=(Name*) malloc(st->size*(sizeof(Name)));
for (i=0; i<st->size; i++){
    fscanf(fp, "%s",&st);
    insert(root,st.surname);/////////I think here is the problem                
    //fscanf(fp, "%s", &st->name[i].firstname);        
   // fscanf(fp, "%d", &st->name[i].id);
    }
fclose(fp);
   }
```

And now I'm trying to create the insert function which is very difficult for me because i cannot understand the arguments that she should take

```
STU *insert(STU *node, char *sname)///What should i use here to save take the Surname??
{
if(node==NULL){
    node=(NODE *) malloc(sizeof(STU));
    strcpy(node->surname);
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right=NULL;
}
else{
    if(strcmp(*sname, node->surname)<0)
        insert(node->left, *sname);
    else if(strcmp(*sname, node->surname)>0)
        insert(node->right, *sname);
}
return node;
}
```

Here is the structure definition:

```
typedef struct Name{
  char firstname[20];   
  int id;
  struct Students *nameleft;
  struct Students *nameright;    
} Name;
typedef struct Students{ 
   char surname[20];    
Name *name;      
int size;
    struct Students *left;
    struct Students *right;     
} Students;
typedef struct Students STU;
struct Students *insert(char num);
struct Students *root=NULL;
```

Can anyone help me correct the insert function because i cannot understand which arguments i must use to save the surname and i will do the rest myself. I think that my problem is the insert function.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you've got the hard part.  The problem is `strcpy` you just want

```
strcpy(node->surname, sname)
```

to copy the surname passed in into the node structure.

As an aside, I'm a little uncomfortable with your freeing `st->name` in your `loadData` function.  What happens the first time you call the function?  Hopefully `st->name` is `NULL`, but a preferable way would be to have a separate destroy function that frees up an entire tree.  Then you can pair the `loadData` and `destroyData` function.  It is always best to have allocates and frees as pairs this way.  It makes it unlikely you will leak memory, double free, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked...well sort of...i have another question..when i complie it says that [  fscanf(fp, "%s",&st);
    insert(root,st.surname) ]  st.surname is int but want st.surname to be a char.(look at LoadData function when i call insert)....It says ([Warning] passing arg 2 of `insert' makes pointer from integer without a cast )

Comment: Yeah, you've mixed up your pointer vs. non-pointer types.  You want the second argument to `insert` to be type `char*`; you have `char`.  When you recurse in `insert` you want the arguments to be simply `sname`, not `*sname`.